# After successfully installing tensorflow, error with the import: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I successfully installed tensorflow, however for some reason if I want to import it using the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I get the following error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I have checked if I installed tensorflow, by using the following command in the Terminal

```
pip3 show tensorflow
```

And I get the following output:

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.13.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
etc....
```

I dont know what the issue is, I have tried to uninstall tensorflow and reinstall it, but that doesnt solve the problem. I am using Visual Studio code on a MacBook. I have already checked my python version (python 3.10.9) and I have checked my pip version (23.3.1), so this shouldn't be a problem

I would be grateful for any help or advice on how to solve this problem.

I have tried to uninstall tensorflow and reinstall it, but that doesnt solve the problem. I am using Visual Studio code on a MacBook. I have already checked my python version (python 3.10.9) and I have checked my pip version (23.3.1), so this shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Execute your code using below command

```
python3 <filename>.py
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesnt work or seem to solve the problem

Comment: what is the python version you are using ?

Comment: Could the problem be that tensorflow is located in the wrong folder?

Comment: seems like your python version is python 3.10.9 , can you downgrade you python version to 3.9 and try it ?

Comment: can you try installing tensorflow using this command python3 -m pip install tensorflow

Comment: I have tried to install tensorflow with the command python3 -m pip install tensorflow, but I still get the message:No module named 'tensorflow'.  the python version I am using is python 3.10.9

Comment: I can try to downgrade the python version however tensorflow should be supported by my python version according to their website

Comment: Ideally it should be I had similar issue earlier , it worked when I switched to 3.9